# What is the fastest way to determine if a given email is valid via command line?

Tags: telnet, email-validation, bulk

I want to automate the validation of a significant number of emails.

My first thought was to run telnet and query the Google SMTP server with each email, but then I would have to parse the output which adds an extra step to the process, which, given the quantity of tests to be run, would make the process infinitely slower.

So, my question is, what is the *most* computationally inexpensive way to test emails for validity in bulk.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to the Google mail exchanger would allow to validate just the email addresses handled by Google itself. On top of that, parsing an SMTP dialog is not an easy thing, provided you need to handle *every* possible SMTP status code. Furthermore, validating lots of email addresses in this way would make Google ban your IP address(es) if you overload its mail exchangers.

That being said and assuming you are running under Windows, if you need to validate your lists of email addresses from the command line I would suggest using our [email validation](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component) library coupled with a simple PowerShell script. Our software supports PowerShell by way of the custom `Verify-EmailAddress` cmdlet or, for advanced scenarios, by way of a handful set of .NET classes which can be easily used from within PowerShell and it can perform [advanced syntax check](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component/features/syntax-validation), DNS validations, [mailbox existence](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component/features/mailbox-existence-check) test and [much more](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component/features).

Here is a short sample showing how to validate a list of email addresses using the built-in `Verify-EmailAddress` cmdlet:

```
'me@example.com', 'you@example.com' |
    ? { (Verify-EmailAddress $_ -Level MailBox).IsSuccess }
```

Finally, if you are familiar with C# please take a look at these [code samples](http://cobisi.com/support/kb/emailverify.net/code-samples), that you may easily convert to PowerShell (just ask us for [help](http://cobisi.com/support/contact-us)).

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I'm really looking for something that can run on Linux.